# My layout adds horizontal scroll and some elements are not centered

Tags: html, css

Ok, I am getting really annoyed by this. I want all my elements to be horizontally positioned in the center of page on smaller devices. But some of them are slightly moved to the side. And my layout is adding horizontal scroll. It is like something is going off screen, but I am not sure what. Also, icons in About us section are not centered vertically. What did I miss? Any help would be appreciated because I am losing my patience and I do not wish to leave it as is.

EDIT: Ok, I managed to deal with overlapping. Navigation menu was causing the fuss. Added overflow: hidden and it solved that problem. Now what remains is, divs that are nested in .flexing and .grid are slightly to the left. Need to be in center.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dyt1cfq/)

```
 <header>
            <nav id="myNav">
                <div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
                </div>
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav><br>
      </header>  

<div class="aboutus">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>About us</h2>
        <hr>
        <h5 style="word-break: keep-all;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h5>
        <section class=" flexing">
            <div data-aos="fade-right">
                <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-aos="fade-right">
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-aos="fade-right">
                <i class="fa fa-google-wallet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-aos="fade-right">
                <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>

        </section>
        <div class="item-link">
            <!-- <div> -->
                <a href="#">Learn more</a>
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lorem" id="work">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-left">
        <div class="grid ipsum">
            <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/kamera.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="lorem-text1">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elementum augue sed est
                    porttitor, ac blandit nisl posuere. Pellentesque hendrerit suscipit mi eu lobortis.
                    Curabitur consectetur enim id elementum accumsan. Quisque metus purus, iaculis id tincidunt
                    non, blandit quis sapien. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lorem" id="dorem">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-left">
        <div class="grid dorem">
            <div class="lorem-text2">
                <h2>Dolor sit amet</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elementum augue sed est
                    porttitor, ac blandit nisl posuere. Pellentesque hendrerit suscipit mi eu lobortis.
                    Curabitur consectetur enim id elementum accumsan. Quisque metus purus, iaculis id tincidunt
                    non, blandit quis sapien. </p>
                <a href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/laptop.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Raleway, Raleway-Bold, Raleway-ExtraLight, ProximaNova- 
 Regular;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}


.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
}

/* NAVIGATION MENU */
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 3;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: black;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}



   
/* ABOUT US */

hr {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}

h2, h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.aboutus {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.flexing {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flexing i {
  display: flex;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: grey;
  margin: auto;
}

.flexing i:hover {
background: lightgreen;
color: white;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.aboutus a {
  width: 180px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  background: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.aboutus a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* LOREM IPSUM PART */

.grid {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.lorem {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 0 40px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.lorem img {
  display: block;
  margin-top:70px;
  max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}

.lorem h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 96px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.lorem p {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.lorem a {
    width: 180px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    background: lightgreen;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lorem a:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

#work {
    background: rgb(238, 237, 237);
}

.lorem-text1 {
    margin-left: 45px ;
}

.lorem-text2 {
    margin-right: 45px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  }


/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
 header {
  width: 100%;
 }

header.sticky {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

nav ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  background: #000;
}

.show-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

nav ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: block;
}


.logo h1 a img {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* ABOUT US */

.aboutus {
  padding: 30px 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.aboutus h2 , .lorem h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 58px;
}

.aboutus h2, .aboutus h5 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* .aboutus p.top {
  padding: 35px 0 30px;
} */

.aboutus i {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  padding-top: 8%;
}

.aboutus h3 {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

.aboutus p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.aboutus a {
  margin: 25px auto 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

section.item {
  text-align: center;
}

.flexing i {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

/* LOREM */

.lorem p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.lorem {
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.lorem img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.lorem-text1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;  
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.lorem-text2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.flexing {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexing div {
  width: 90%;;
}

.grid {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
}

#dorem a{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  
}

#work {
  background: white;  
}

#work a {
  margin: auto;
}

.dorem {
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  /* margin: auto; */
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
  .lorem p {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  
  .lorem {
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -30px;
  }
  
  .lorem img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  .lorem-text1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;  
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .lorem-text2 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .flexing {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .flexing div {
    width: 90%;;
  }
  
  .grid {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  #dorem a{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    
  }
  
  #work {
    background: white;  
  }
  
  #work a {
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .dorem {
    /* display: flex; */
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    /* margin: auto; */
}

}
```

Comment: Fyi, header tag is not closed.

Comment: It is, I just did not copy it correctly. :)

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: A link or a codepen example would be helpful

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your .container class may be causing the centering issue, it's 80% wide. This works, but is easier to work with if it's 100%, and then pushed off each side of the screen with a padding or margin value on each side. You have margin auto on each side, you could use margin 5% on each side, for example. If you have to use overflow: hidden on the full page, something is wrong, so that means that the problems will propagate. Undo the overflow:hidden and try to find the element that sticks out to the right. That is the element that is wrong. The container may be 80% of this too wide element, and everything inside it will be slightly off center.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned, nav menu was sticking out to the right. So, I added overflow: hidden to it. What baffles me is that sometimes when is shrink the page, it looks fine and sometimes it does not. Maybe it is the browser? Or maybe something is off with the width, but what? As for the centering part, I added margin-left: 5% aaand it seems to work. It might be a bit "rough" method, but if it works and is legit, I will take it.

Comment: As I mentioned, if the nav menu was sticking out to the right, that's an error, because of badly structured html or css. There is no such thing as unwanted overflow on a healthy web page. That error should be fixed first of all, and then the subsequent errors may be easier to fix.